# Is it possible to use adb backup in order to make a clone of a tablet?

Tags: backup, adb, restore

Is it possible to use adb backup in order to make a copy of tablet? In fact I want to recover the contents of a tablet using adb backup and then install it on the tablet that have the same type with the same version of Android using adb restore  backup.ab.

Comment: Just to make clear - the ROM *must* be identical, otherwise there will be room for errors, force-closes etc. The part is not 100% clear - do you have two identical tablets - same make, manufacturer, ROM? (Am not 100% sure if you're implying to adb backup and restore on to the same tablet - hence my comment) :)

Comment: I have two identical tablet but not the some list of application installed in both. i used the first and i executed adb backup -all. Then i executed  restore for the second, i found their is  icon of some application that are installed in only one of them, but when i try to run application. i have a message application is not installed

Comment: Did you sign into your Google account on the second tablet (the *destination* of the adb backup)?

Comment: uses, i use the some google count

Answer (score 0):

We already had this question as part of [Restoring an ADB backup onto a different phone of the same model?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37570/16575). It should be possible, at least theoretically, and at least when all devices are of the same brand and model as well as share the same Android version.