# I want to transfer my android internet app info (saved passwords/log on info on browser)

Tags: samsung, internet, cache

I have a note 3 and will be transferring to my note 5 soon.
I want to find out if there is anyway i can just transfer the app with the existing internet browsing info with the login info i already have in the cache.  The cache has not been cleared so I want to directly transfer this to my new phone so i don't have to re-log into and re-enter all my passwords for the sites.

Is there a way to do this?

Just to be clear:
I want to open up my internet app on note 5 as it is on my note 3....so that the login info and stuff is already there so i don't have to find all my logon info again for the sites i visit.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution without root is described in [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575): using `adb backup` you can grab all (or selected) apps including their data from your old device, and then restore them to your new device. I'd recommend taking separate backups from all your apps, as `adb restore` is an all-or-nothing without the possibility to select what to restore – and you probably want a "clean transfer", leaving "garbage" out.

#### Instructions

So the recommended steps would be:

1. installing the required ADB stuff to your computer, see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)
2. performing an ADB backup for all your apps. If you're using Linux on your computer, my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) can assist you with that, creating shell scripts to backup/restore each single app and more (on Windows, [Ultimate Backup Tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1844032) might offer something comparable). If not, you can list all apps via `adb shell pm list packages <X>` (with `<X>` being `-3` for user apps you want to backup including their `.apk` files, and `-s` for system apps where you want only the data from – as you couldn't restore the `.apk` anyway due to read-only `/system` file system). Then run `adb backup -f <appname>.ab -apk <user_app_package_name>` for each user app, and `adb backup -f <appname>.ab -noapk` for each system app. Hint: `com.android.sharedstoragebackup` will take a while and create a huge file, and you probably can skip that; it's the contents of your SD card(s).
3. for each backup file you want to transfer to the new device, run `adb restore <file.ab>` with the new device connected

#### A few caveats and tricks

- apps may opt-out of this backup (`ALLOW_BACKUP = FALSE`), in which case the backup file will be only 41 bytes large (or 0 bytes). In this case, you cannot transfer the app this way without root tricks.
- you could simply do a "full backup" of the entire system, and later pick what to restore with the help of some 3rd party tools – see [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575) and [Partial adb restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24785/16575)

#### Further readings

- [Restoring an ADB backup onto a different phone of the same model?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37570/16575)
- our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)
- our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)
- if the above sounds "too much", and you want a few selected apps only: [my list of backup apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_141) has a.o. *Helium* mentioned, which might be worth a look then. It does the same as described above, just directly on the Android device.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I wish you guys were beside me.....I will try this first without rooting the phone to see how it goes.

Comment: I use that regularly (though all my devices are rooted, so Tanmay's solution runs via its automatic scheduler in the background as well). Except for those opted-out apps (which I "opted in" again with root powers), it works very well – which is why I'm confident it will be your solution, @Tom. When solved, please don't forget to mark the answer which solved your issue by ticking the check-mark next to it, so others in a similar situation can easily identify it :) Fingers crossed the app you're after has not opted-out!

Comment: Is there any workaround to force backup for apps that prevent backups (`ALLOW_BACKUP = FALSE`)? (without rooting)

Comment: @dma_k without rooting, no. With root & Xposed, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Titanium backup (requires root access on both old and new devices)

Make the backup of the internet app on note 3, copy the backup in your new device, download Titanium Backup in new device, restore the backup but be sure to restore only the data. Titanium backup offers 3 types of app restores: App only, App+Data, Data only. Use the "Data Only" option as using the "App+Data" restore option may replace the internet app with an older version (Note 3 would have older app version than Note 5).

This shall restore all the saved data of your old device to your new device.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try this out as well!  Really wish you guys were beside me.....